# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple query that selects a PIN from a list of numbers, and then assigns that PIN to a user and inserts it into another table:

```
$sth = $this->db->query("SELECT available_pins FROM pin_list ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1 ;");
$pinarray = $sth->fetch();
$this->user_pin = $pinarray;

$sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_pin) VALUES(:user_email,  :user_pin) ;");
$sth->execute(array(':user_email' => $this->user_email, ':user_pin' => $this->user_pin));
```

However, this creates a Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, any ideas?

**Additional info**

$sth->execute(array gives the error, available_pins uses mediumint(6). It is a list of random 6 digit numbers.

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: $sth->execute(array gives the error.

Comment: You might want to add a VALUES clause to that INSERT statement. You're just assuming it's worked - you need to check return values and handle things appropriately when they fail.

Comment: I had a typo; VALUES are in the INSERT statement as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$pinarray` is an instance of StdClass. You probably intend to grab the `available_pins` field, eh?

```
$pinarray = $sth->fetch();
$this->user_pin = $pinarray->available_pins;
```

Comment: I think it's two fold, he's trying to pass in an array of values to the execute statement, but instead they should be bound using `bind_param()` no?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'd just be guessing with respect to the DB abstraction layer that is being used in `$sth`. Some use the syntax shown in the question.